# Is there a simple way to set a default font for the whole app?

Tags: .net, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm developping an app with monotouch and I must provide a way to change the font for the whole application.

I know I could just set every of my controls font individually but that sounds like a pita ... Is there some kind of application.defaultFont or something similar ?

Also , I'd like to let the user choose that font and it's color , is there a built-in control which does that ? It'd be even greater if I could do that in the iphone settings for the app .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a notion of configurable default fonts and styles in an iPhone app, which is unfortunate as it would be really handy.

One way to make up for the lack of this is to have a StyleManager class which gets passed various UI items after they've been instantiated and sets fonts, colours etc.

The iPhone settings app (i.e. the place for settings outside your app proper) only has a limited range of UI controls possible, so you're going to have limited luck allowing choosing of arbitrary colours there. For in-app settings you can implement what you like in terms of settings.

Comment: Also, there are some interesting situations where iOS will actually change the colour of some labels in the UI after creation: if you're showing a UISplitViewController on the iPad, iOS provides its own (non-configurable!) default style for popovers, which actually has different colours in portrait versus landscape mode. So if you set the colour of some text in a UIToolbar, on the iPad you can later find your colour overridden by the OS!