# How to make theme based iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, themes, background-color

I want implement theme property in my application project in iPhone. I have near about 5-6 background color at level one and 1 more background at level two and 3 images which I want to change on the change of theme.

I want to control all the colors from one central location.

Tell me the best way to achieve this or any tutorial for it or any sample code for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to create multi-theme application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192957/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-multi-theme-application)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class (singleton preferably) that handles this.

```
@interface Themes {
    int    theme;   //or you can create a enum
}

-(UIColor *)colorForBackground;        //or any other component
-(UIImage *)backgroundImageForButton;  //..
-(NSString *)xibNameForController:(NSString *)controller;   //or you can add a enum/define for controllers

@property() int theme;   // used to change or get the current theme; You can also send a NSNotification when the theme is changed, so that the content is refreshed
@end

@implementation Themes
@synthesize theme;

-(UIColor *)colorForBackground{
    if(theme==0){
        return [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    if(theme==1){
        return [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    //etc.
}
-(NSString *)xibNameForController:(NSString *)controller{
    if([controller isEqualToString:@"MailController"]){
        if(theme==0)
            return @"MainControllerTheme0";
        //...
    }
    //...
}
//..
@end
```