# Is there a way to change default font for your application

Tags: ios, fonts

As I understand all standard controls use system font by default.

Also, API [UIFont systemFontOfSize: ] uses system font too.

Is there a way to redefine it for the whole application, instead of setting a font for table, labels and so on?

Comment: Did you try make a category for UIFont?

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to change it? This is how jarring interfaces are born.

Comment: @Dave: Yes. I am sure I want to change it :)

Comment: @NeverBe: Interesting idea. I will try it. However, there is a chance that standard control behavior bypass this particular method

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is no, you cant change apple's systemFont, you need to set the font on your control yourself.

For best way to set a default font for whole iOS app, please check the below SO questions:

[Set a default font for whole iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707082/set-a-default-font-for-whole-ios-app)

[How to set a custom font for entire iOS app without specifying size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907761/how-to-set-a-custom-font-for-entire-ios-app-without-specifying-size)

[How do I set a custom font for the whole application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607108/how-do-i-set-a-custom-font-for-the-whole-application)

[Is there a simple way to set a default font for the whole app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141132/is-there-a-simple-way-to-set-a-default-font-for-the-whole-app)

Answer (score 5):

Define and export (by including a header in files or in precompiled header) a category of `UIFont` as following:

```
@implementation UIFont (Utils)

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

+ (UIFont *)systemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOUR_TRUETYPE_FONT_NAME_HERE" size:size];
}

+ (UIFont *)lightSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOUR_TRUETYPE_FONT_NAME_HERE" size:size];
}

+ (UIFont *)boldSystemFontOfSize:(CGFloat)size
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOUR_TRUETYPE_FONT_NAME_HERE" size:size];
}

+ (UIFont *)preferredFontForTextStyle:(NSString *)style
{
    if ([style isEqualToString:UIFontTextStyleBody])
        return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    if ([style isEqualToString:UIFontTextStyleHeadline])
        return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    if ([style isEqualToString:UIFontTextStyleSubheadline])
        return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    if ([style isEqualToString:UIFontTextStyleFootnote])
        return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    if ([style isEqualToString:UIFontTextStyleCaption1])
        return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    if ([style isEqualToString:UIFontTextStyleCaption2])
        return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
    return [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

Light variant comes as a useful extra starting with iOS 7. Enjoy! ;)

Comment: @orj Why is this not a good idea ? this doesn't seem to be using a undocumented api's . or is it ?

Comment: Well, it overloads standard implementation of these methods in UIKit, which is not completely recommended; f.e. iOS 9 comes with adaptive switching of system font between San Francisco _Display_ and _Text_ variants depending on a requested font size.  I still found this technique **safe** though, unless you are writing a typographic app or need some font extras, this is very easy and quick way to switch default app fonts in a pretty deterministic way.