# override preferredStatusBarStyle in UIViewConrtoller extension

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'd like to override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in an extension of `UIViewController` like this:

```
extension UIViewController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
      return .lightContent
    }
}
```

The compiler throws this error `Getter for 'preferredStatusBarStyle' with Objective-C selector 'preferredStatusBarStyle' conflicts with method 'preferredStatusBarStyle()' with the same Objective-C selector`

Applying the same override to `UINavigationController` instead of `UIViewController` works; but preferredStatusBarStyle is a var that is inherited by UIViewController.

-> Why is it possible to apply this extension to `UINavigationController` but not to `UIViewController`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't override (re-declare implementation of) already implemented properties this way via extensions in *Swift* on a class which introduces the property.

You should definitely create a `UIViewController` subclass and use it app-wide instead.

There's an option, however. You can override this using *Objective-C* by providing an extending category, similar thing applied to `UIFont` answered here: [Is there a way to change default font for your application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197033/is-there-a-way-to-change-default-font-for-your-application/25867245#25867245). However, it's not completely safe to do so and you should expect unicorns to come when not careful enough.

Comment: Thank you michi. I don't like the idea of having my custom base class of UIViewController, hence I'd have to implement this in every UIViewController class again and again...

Comment: No you wouldn't, all you need to do is inherit all other controllers from `MyBaseViewController` instead of `UIViewController` and implement the generic stuff in your `MyBaseViewController`. This is probably a recommended way.

Comment: That is exactly what I had in mind when I said "I don't like the idea of having my custom base class of UIViewController"